# How to check if a game object is active when outside of its script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a function in the Patient script which adds the patients to the DoctorsPatients list, effectively "assigning" that patient to the doctor. This works fine, but now I want to remove the patients from this list if they are inactive. I am trying to use the Update() function in Doctor to periodically check the list for inactive patients and remove them.

Doctor script:

```
 public class Doctor : Monobehaviour
{

 public List<Patient> DoctorsPatients = new List<Patient>();

 void Update()
    {
        foreach(Patient pat in DoctorsPatients)
        {
            if (pat.activeSelf == false)
            {
                DoctorsPatients.Remove(pat);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried adding in

```
Patient patient;
```

in the variables section and changed the loop to this:

```
        foreach(Patient pat in DoctorsPatients)
        {
            patient = pat.GetComponent<Patient>(); //Target the script?? sometimes works
            if (patient.activeSelf == false)
            {
                DoctorsPatients.Remove(patient);
            }
        }
```

and I get the same error: " error CS1061: 'Patient' does not contain a definition for 'activeSelf' and no accessible extension method 'activeSelf' accepting a first argument of type 'Patient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

It seems like I get an error like this every time I want to access game objects from other game objects but this time I cannot solve it with google alone. Thanks.

Comment: So refer to its game object. Whatever then Patient class is. I assume a monobehavior you can access its gameobject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

- [`activeSelf`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeSelf.html) is implemented in [`GameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) so since your `Patient` class seems to be a [`MonoBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) you can get it via its property [`gameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour-gameObject.html) so it would simply be

  ```
  if(!pat.gameObject.activeSelf)
  ```
- **BUT** while iterating a collection using `foreach` you **may not** alter this collection by removing elements from it!

  You could however combine both things using [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall) which in one call goes through the entire list and removes all elements fulfilling a certain condition

  ```
  DoctorsPatients.RemoveAll(pat => !pat && !pat.gameObject.activeSelf);
  ```

  where `pat` is the iteration variable just like in `foreach(var pat in DoctorsPatients)`.

  I just added also the `!pat` to first filter also out any already destroyed instance before accessing and checking the `gameObject` of it to prevent any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Realized from the answer by DerHugo that I needed to use `pat.gameObject.activeSelf()`. It appears gameObject is a separate thing from the MonoBehaviour object. I came up with my own solution since I couldnt figure out how to get `RemoveAll` to cooperate with my `foreach` loop as DerHugo suggested.

Here's my solution using a standard for loop that allows me to remove elements while iterating:

```
for(int i = 0; i<DoctorsPatients.Count; i++)
{
    if (!DoctorsPatients[i].gameObject.activeSelf)
    {
        DoctorsPatients.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple: You don't use `RemoveAll` in a loop at all ;) it replaces the entire loop and gets the job done in one single call as mentioned ;)

Comment: What you do now is not good: after removing an element the `DoctorsPatients.Count` is now actually smaller then before but you keep increasing `i` -> you might miss some elements!